# Split string on character, except that doubled up character is an escape

Tags: regex, powershell, split

Input:

```
$string = "this-is-just-an--example"
```

Output:

```
this
is
just
an-example
```

Tried various things centered around Regex.Split and "-[^-]" or "-([^])".
Example of things that did not work:

```
[regex]::Split( $string, "-[^-]" )
[regex]::Split( $string, "-([^-])" )
```

Of course I can use the String.Split and iterate, and realize that empty string means I ran into escaped character... But it's ugly code.
P.S. tried searching for duped for a few minutes, didn't find any.

Comment: `(?<!-)-(?!-)` would match on single dashes only, but it doesn't work for example on a---b-c -> a--, b, c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the lookahead and lookbehind assertions, and then do a replace to eliminate the remaining doubled characters:

```
$string = "this-is-just-an--example"
$string -split '(?<!-)-(?!-)' -replace '--','-'

this
is
just
an-example
```

Comment: Interesting.  Accepted, and then downvoted with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the escape sequence with another value first eliminates the need for a complex split condition. All that is needed is a unique replacement value that does not already appear in the string.

For example, using `@` as the replacement value for `$string = 'this-is-just-an--example'`, the following line will get the desired result:

```powershell
$string -replace '--','@' -split '-' -replace '@','-'
```

- `-replace '--','@'` eliminates the escape sequence (giving `this-is-just-an@example`),
- `-split '-'` then separates the result (giving an array containing `this`, `is`, `just`, and `an@example`),
- and finally `-replace '@','-'` restores the escaped value (giving `this`, `is`, `just`, `an-example`).

Both [`-split`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113270) and [`-replace`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113217) are built-in PowerShell operators that work on strings using regular expressions (equivalent to the [`Regex.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split.aspx) and [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) methods in .NET).